# Unable to figure out this issue with a choice part of a simple text game im making

Tags: python, game-development

What I am trying to get it to do is give an initial choice about a "vial" that the player stumbles across. If the player picks it up, I want it to say something like "you acquired water" and then end. If they say No I just want the code to end so that they can proceed in the game. My trouble comes when I try to account for errors (like if someone puts in a 't' rather than a "Yes" or a "No". I have tried many different models and none of them seem to work. Here is an example of how I want it to behave:

If answer is yes:

You find a vial would you like to pick it up?
y
You have acquired 0.4 oz of water
You continue your journey

If answer is No:

You find a vial would you like to pick it up?
n
You continue your journey

If the answer is invalid:

You find a vial would you like to pick it up?
t
no you really need to decide this
t
You were killed
Game over
would you like to restart this section?
(and then tying in es would restart from the vial question)

---

My Current code:

```
keword = False
answer_yes = 'y' and 'yes' and 'Yes'
answer_no = 'n' and 'no' and 'No'

while not keword:
    print('water. pick up?')
    question = input(   )
    if question == answer_yes:
        print('You have picked up 0.4 oz of water')
        answered = True
        keword = True

    if question == answer_no:
        answered = True
        keword = True

    else:
        answered = False
        keword = True

while answered == False:
    print('no you need to answer')
    recon = input(   )
    if recon == answer_yes:
        print('You have picked up 0.4 oz of water')
        answered = True
    if recon == answer_no:
        answered = True
    else:
        print('You have died the trees ate you. That sucks.')
        print('would you like to restart?')
        restart = input(    )
```

If any of you have an answer to this that would be cool!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]? Have you searched for an answer already? Have you created a [mre]?

Comment: Have you tried basic debugging? For example, check the value of `answer_yes` in a debugger, or add `print(repr(answer_yes))` if you don't use a debugger. That should put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `answer_yes` to `'y' and 'yes' and 'Yes'` will not work, as `and` is a boolean operator, so it only works with `True` and `False` values.

The code you're looking for is:

```
answer_yes = ['y','yes']
answer_no = ['n','no']
```

and for your if statements, instead of `if question == answer_yes:` use `if question.lower() in answer_yes`.
Enclosing a group of values in square brackets seperated by commas creates a List, and using the `in` operator checks if a given item exists in a list.

The `question.lower()` converts it to lowercase, removing the need for including the capitalised versions in the lists.